# Passing dict through views with JSON and AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

I have a view in which I create a dictionary, let's say:

```
my_dict = {str(v): v*2 for v in range(2,8)}
my_dict['Total'] = {'Tip': 'Reconsider life choices'}
# bit of humour here
>> {'2': 4, '3': 6, '4': 8, '5': 10, '6': 12, '7': 14, 'Total': {'Tip': 'Reconsider life choices'}}
```

I pass it to my context dict as `'my_dict_json': json.dumps(my_dict)`.

In my template, I reconstruct it with:

```
<button id="btn_exp" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendDicts()">
<script>
  var d = JSON.parse('{{my_dict_json|safe}}');
  // This is a function I bind to the onclick attr of a button
  function sendDicts(){
    $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'my_model:intended_view' %}',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                'my_dict': d,
                'another_dict': d2
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
  }
</script>
```

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but my intended view is decorated with `@csrf_exempt`, anyways, when I inspect (debug) the intended view, I notice that the `request` var has no data on it's `POST` and what seems to be the dictionaries are on `request.body` as a binary string with a lot of `%`s, if I try to use `json.loads(request.body.decode())`, it fails miserably with:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it by removing `contentType: 'application/json'`, can't figure why but... it's working.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse is supposed to handle a string containing properties names in double quotes like this : '{"2": 4, "3": 6}'

Comment: Shouldn't `$.ajax()` stringify keys?